# I want to take out the coordinates acquired in the delegate

Tags: swift, core-location

I wrote a program that uses LocationManagerDelegate to display coordinates in the debug area whenever the current location changes. Got an error when retrieving coordinates

**Can not use instance member 'locationManager' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available**

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   setUpLocationManager()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func setUpLocationManager() {
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    guard let locationManager = locationManager else {return}
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 10
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        printLocation()
    }
}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) ->Optional<Any> {
    let location = locations.first
    let latitude = location?.coordinate.latitude
    let longitude = location?.coordinate.longitude
    let latlong = [latitude, longitude]
    return latlong
}
let myLocation = locationManager()

func printLocation() {
    print("test\(myLocation)")
}

}
```

test (Function) 
is output

```
let myLocation = locationManager ()
```

When you change to

```
let myLocation = locationManager
```

Comment: Why do you have `let myLocation = locationManager()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains a few mistakes.

The error occurs because you cannot execute the affected line on the top level of the class.

---

First of all you **must not** change signatures of delegate methods. This *custom* delegate method

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) ->Optional<Any> { ...
```

will **never** be called.

And apart from that why do you declare the return type as `Any?` although it's supposed to be `[CLLocationCoordinate2D]`?

---

- Create the location manager immediately, replace

  ```
  var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
  ```

  with

  ```
  let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
  ```
- In `setUpLocationManager()` delete the lines

  ```
  locationManager = CLLocationManager()
  guard let locationManager = locationManager else {return} // this line is completely pointless anyway



  printLocation()
  ```
- The delegate method `didUpdateLocations` is called periodically and **asynchronously**. Print the result inside the method

  ```
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
      guard let location = locations.first else { return }
      let latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
      let longitude = location.coordinate.longitude
      let latlong = [latitude, longitude]
      print("test", latlong)
  }
  ```
- Delete

  ```
  let myLocation = locationManager()

  func printLocation() {
      print("test\(myLocation)")
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to confirm the intended operation.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to confirm the intended operation.I changed it to return latlong to func printLocation ().
I wanted to take the value of latlong out of the function and make it available to other functions.

Comment: As I said you cannot return something from `didUpdateLocations`, but you could declare `printLocation` taking a parameter e.g. `printLocation(_ location: CLLocation) { ... }`

Comment: Well, it was very helpful. I will review the definition of the function.